# How to read different partition formats in Avro from S3 to Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, avro

I have a S3 bucket with two partition formats:

1. S3://bucketname/tablename/year/month/day
2. S3://bucketname/tablename/device/year/month/day

The file format is Avro.

I tried to read by `val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("s3://S3://bucketname/tablename")`.

The error info is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting partition column names detected:

    Partition column name list #0: xx, yy
    Partition column name list #1: xx

For partitioned table directories, data files should only live in leaf directories.
And directories at the same level should have the same partition column name.
Please check the following directories for unexpected files or inconsistent partition column names:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read them both at the same time. As mentioned in the error itself,

> Directories at the same level should have the same partition column
>   name.

Read both of them separately (using 2 s3 paths up to the leaf) and then you can `union` your input DFs if the schema matches.